# Is there any downside to overloading functions in rust using a trait & generic function?

Tags: rust

I find this is particularly useful pattern to allow method overloading:

```
struct Foo {
  value:uint
}

trait HasUIntValue {
  fn as_uint(self) -> uint;
}

impl Foo {
  fn add<T:HasUIntValue>(&mut self, value:T) {
    self.value += value.as_uint();
  }
}

impl HasUIntValue for int {
  fn as_uint(self) -> uint {
    return self as uint;
  }
}

impl HasUIntValue for f64 {
  fn as_uint(self) -> uint {
    return self as uint;
  }
}

#[test]
fn test_add_with_int()
{
  let mut x = Foo { value: 10 };
  x.add(10i);
  assert!(x.value == 20);
}

#[test]
fn test_add_with_float()
{
  let mut x = Foo { value: 10 };
  x.add(10.0f64);
  assert!(x.value == 20);
}
```

Is there any meaningful downside to doing this?

Comment: If your “overloaded” function needs to operate on an object that can do <something>, use a trait. Otherwise, you’d probably be better off casting earlier or using multiple functions.

Comment: One can even go crazier: double dispatch. check out, how hashing is done in Rust.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no downside; this is exactly the pattern to implement overloading in Rust.

There are a number of types in the standard library which do exactly this. For example, there is [BytesContainer](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/path/trait.BytesContainer.html) trait in [path](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/path/) module, which is implemented for various kinds of strings and vectors.

Answer (score 4):

There is *at least* one downside: it cannot be an afterthought.

In C++, ad-hoc overloading allows you to overload a function over which you have no control (think 3rd party), whereas in Rust this is not actually doable.

That being said, ad-hoc overloading is mostly useful in C++ because of ad-hoc templates, which is the only place where you cannot know in advance which function the call will ultimately resolve to. In Rust, since templates are bound by traits, the fact that overloading cannot be an afterthought is not an issue since only the traits functions can be called anyway.